# Unable to use google map V2 inside fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I know this question has already been asked a few times, but I cant find a solution to my problem by looking at them. I have created a navigation drawer. The navigation drawer naturally helps switching fragments. Inside one such fragment, I want to show up a google map.

The **map_fragment.xml**:

```
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

The **MapFragment**:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;



public class MapFragment extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, container, false);

        GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    return view;


     }


}
```

The line:

```
GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Always shows:

**Cannot cast from Fragment to SupportMapFragment**

I am not sure why is this showing up? Where am I going wrong? I have provided all the required permissions in the Manifest as I am able to see google map in other activities.

Comment: asked many times ... you should decide "support" or "normal" ... do not use both at the same time ...

Comment: @Selvin either of the combination is not working in my case

Comment: omg, not working? what does it mean? there is no such word in programmer's dictionary .... anyway check imports ... learn what is a class hierarchy ... i'm pretty sure that SupportMapFragment is not derived from android.app.Fragment ... but  MapFragment is ...

Answer (score 1):

**This is best practice to use google map , try it.**

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, container, false);

   // GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    MapFragment map = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    map.getMapAsync(this);
return view;


 }

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    //googleMap is your map

    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    gm = googleMap;

    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Ancona, 5));
}

}
```

Comment: put this import : 
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;